# How to make "my account or settings " clickable?

Tags: android

Here is the screen shot of my sidebar navigation bar.

[image]

I want to make the items in the sidebar navigation Menu clickable so that I can move to another Activity how can I do this?

Comment: No hard feelings but first of all you should search on Google or read some documentation about implementation `NavigationView` which I suppose you are using. And now your question `navigationView.onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` wil help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to treat these as Menu items.

When you set up the navigation bar from the layout XML you attach a menu.xml to it which contains menu items that are then displayed in the navigation bar.

Method 1:

Now from the activity where you have your navigation bar variable you need to get the menu from the navigation view object.

```
Menu menu = navigation_view.getMenu();
```

Then you can get individual menuItems from this menu object.

```
MenuItem myAccount = menu.getItem(0);
MenuItem settingsItem = menu.getItem(1);
MenuItem logoutItem = menu.getItem(2);
```

Now you can use each of this menuItem objects to set menu click listeners on them and then start the next activity from there. e.g.

```
myAccount.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ToAcitivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Similarly, you can use rest of the objects and make them clickable.

Method 2:
You can also use

```
navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Second one being more simpler to use